# R MICE Imputations NHANES

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, imputation, r-mice

I'd like to impute an NHANES dataset that contains both missing values and values that need to get imputed since they are below a threshold (Limit of detection(LOD)). MICE imputation is straightforward, but I'd like to constrain the prediction between 0 and the LOD. However, if I just run MICE there can be the introduction of negative values. Since I cannot attach the whole dataset on here, I'll have part of it within this. When a 'NA' value is present for LXB156LA it means that it is below LOD or missing. If it is below LOD there will be a value in LXB156LA_upper. I want to vectorize the constraint so it goes through all columns of my data and doesn't give a MICE imputation value above the 'upper' column value.

Other imputation packages (zCompositions) for example let you put a constraint based on a separate dataset (what I've tried to do in my code - Dn.N.M). This is added to the 'dl' in zComposition imputations. See example here:

```
Complete.Matrix.1 <- multKM(Dn.M, label=0, dl= Dn.N.M, n.draws = 1000)
```

Here is my current workflow:

1. Remove values that are below LOD and introduce them as "NA" when creating a dataframe in R.
2. Add co-variates that affect other columns
3. Impute using the following MICE method `imputed_data <- mice(df, m = 5, maxit = 10, meth = "norm.predict", seed = 3985)`

As mentioned earlier, values can be introduced as either negative or above the LOD (physically impossible). In the NHANES dataset there are columns that indicate that a value is below LOD. These correspond to columns in the dataset. For example, LCB156LA is the column I'd like to impute and I can use column LCB156LC to determine if a value is below detection (binary where 1-below LOD and 0-above LOD). How can I constrain MICE to impute a value between 0 and what is in that cell?

There is an example here of constraint between 0 - 25 (https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Passive_Post_processing/Passive_imputation_post_processing.html), but my upper bounds are specific to the cell itself so this does not help.

I tried to vectorize the `mice::squeeze` function, but that did not work.

There are 3 formats I can make my datasets if that helps:

1. NHANES dataset with values below LOD removed. Indicator columns for which ones are below are added to the dataset (ends with LC in column name).
2. NHANES dataset is identical to the above, except instead of empty cells the LOD is imputed into the cell. Indicator columns are still within the dataset.
3. LOD values for samples that are below the LOD.

Please let me know if it is possible to constrain MICE using these inputs or if there is some general documentation to constrain MICE with these inputs.

Here is the code so far:

```
#Author: M. Dereviankin
#Date: 16-Aug-2022
#Title: NHANES Imputation based on demographics & Predictive Modelling

library(mice)
library(tidyverse)
library(VIM)
library(GGally)
library(caret)
library(tidymodels)
library(dplyr)
library(yardstick)
library(mosaic)
```

## MICE Imputation 2003-2004 -----------------------------------------------

```
df <- read.csv('2003_2004_template.csv', stringsAsFactors = TRUE, na.strings = c("", NA))

df
     SEQN LBX156LA LBX156LA_upper
1 21005       NA      0.1555635
2 21008     2.30             NA
3 21009     6.92             NA

#Specify the Non-Detects
Detect <- read.csv("Detect.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dim(Detect)# 50 44
NonDetect <- read.csv("Non_Detect.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dim(NonDetect)# 50 44

Detect
     SEQN LBX156LA 
1 21005       NA   
2 21008     2.30   
3 21009     6.92 

NonDetect  

    SEQN  LBX156LA
1 21005 0.1555635
2 21008 0.0000000
3 21009 0.0000000

# Remove the first 2 columns ( we dont need them for the imputation)
Detected <- Detect[,-c(1,1)]
dim(Detected)
NonDetected <- NonDetect[,-c(1,1)]
dim(NonDetected)

# Transform to a matrix
Detect.Matrix <- as.matrix(Detected)
dim(Detect.Matrix)
res_detect <- colSums(Detect.Matrix==0)/nrow(Detect.Matrix)*100
res.detect.matrix <- rbind(Detect.Matrix, res_detect)

dim(Detect.Matrix)
NonDetect.Matrix <- as.matrix(NonDetected)
dim(NonDetect.Matrix)

#Subset the 2 matrices
Dn.M   <- Detect.Matrix[,colSums(Detect.Matrix != 0) >=5]
Dn.M.removed <- Detect.Matrix[,colSums(Detect.Matrix != 0) < 5 ]
dim(Dn.M)

Dn.N.M <- NonDetect.Matrix[,colSums(NonDetect.Matrix== 0) >=5]
dim(Dn.N.M)

#Now apply the right method

imputed_data <- mice(Detect.Matrix, m = 5, maxit = 10, meth = "norm.predict", post = Dn.N.M, seed = 3985)
summary(imputed_data)

#finish the dataset

finished_imputed_data <- complete(imputed_data)

#Print off finished dataset

write_csv(finished_imputed_data, "finished_imputed_data_norm.predict.csv")
```

I get the following error:
Error: length(post) does not match ncol(data)

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of any code that you have so far?

Comment: @jrcalabrese The code is updated above

Comment: Since we can't access `2003_2004_template_2.csv` or your other .csv files, could you make your post reproducible by using accessible datasets like `mtcars` or `iris`? You could also provide parts of your dataset with `dput(df)`.

Comment: Hi, I've added a df input example within the code so you can see how the dataset is arranged. Using mtcars or iris won't work for this example.

Comment: Can you also provide your datasets, `Detect.csv` and `Non_Detect.csv`?

Comment: I've added examples of those format as well into the code

Comment: Hi I've added those datasets.

Answer (score 1):

It's still a bit difficult to understand what you intend with your code. The way you use `post = Dn.N.M` doesn't make any sense to me. `post` needs to be a named vector of character strings, like in the mice documentation you attached. Not a matrix of numbers, which is what it looks like you're using. But I think I can still give some advice on what you're trying to achieve.

The difficulty is that `squeeze()` from mice only allows a single lower and upper bound. You correctly note this. What we can do is write our own function, `vec_squeeze()`, which will take a matrix of lower and upper bounds and squeeze the values into that range. Then we carefully code the mice post-processing to take the appropriate imputed values and data values and squeeze it. Example below. First we create the example data.

```r
library(mice)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mice'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     cbind, rbind
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
# Randomly set detection levels independently for different ids
# Can instead set the LOD1 and LOD2 variables to constants, if the
# same LOD for all observations
observed_data <- data.frame(
  measure1 = runif(n, min = -0.5, max = 2),
  measure2 = runif(n, min = -0.5, max = 2),
  LOD1 = runif(n),
  LOD2 = runif(n))
head(observed_data)
#>     measure1 measure2      LOD1       LOD2
#> 1  0.2189438 1.723848 0.1428000 0.66511519
#> 2  1.4707628 1.232009 0.4145463 0.09484066
#> 3  0.5224423 1.101267 0.4137243 0.38396964
#> 4  1.7075435 1.985674 0.3688455 0.27438364
#> 5  1.8511682 1.139264 0.1524447 0.81464004
#> 6 -0.3861088 1.271326 0.1388061 0.44851634

# make the first 5 in measure1 missing, to view easier 
observed_data[1:5, "measure1"] <- NA
# make any negative values NA, to be imputed
observed_data[which(observed_data$measure1 < 0), "measure1"] <- NA
observed_data[which(observed_data$measure2 < 0), "measure2"] <- NA
head(observed_data)
#>   measure1 measure2      LOD1       LOD2
#> 1       NA 1.723848 0.1428000 0.66511519
#> 2       NA 1.232009 0.4145463 0.09484066
#> 3       NA 1.101267 0.4137243 0.38396964
#> 4       NA 1.985674 0.3688455 0.27438364
#> 5       NA 1.139264 0.1524447 0.81464004
#> 6       NA 1.271326 0.1388061 0.44851634
```

Then we define the post-processing and do the imputations.

```
# use vec_squeeze() to constrain between 0 and LOD.
vec_squeeze <- function(x, bounds) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == nrow(bounds))
  pmin(pmax(x, bounds[,1]), bounds[,2])
}
# Initialize a vector to fill with the post-processing commands
ini <- mice(observed_data, maxit = 0)
newpost <- ini$post

# Here there be dragons
newpost["measure1"] <- 
  "imp[[j]][, i] <- vec_squeeze(
    x = imp[[j]][, i], 
    bounds = matrix(c(rep(0, sum(!r[, j])), data[!r[, j], 'LOD1']),
                    nrow = sum(!r[, j])))"
newpost["measure2"] <- 
  "imp[[j]][, i] <- vec_squeeze(
    x = imp[[j]][, i], 
    bounds = matrix(c(rep(0, sum(!r[, j])), data[!r[, j], 'LOD2']),
                    nrow = sum(!r[, j])))"

# Run imputations and view one of the completed datasets
imps <- mice(observed_data,
             meth = "norm.predict",
             post = newpost,
             printFlag = FALSE)
head(complete(imps))
#>    measure1 measure2      LOD1       LOD2
#> 1 0.1428000 1.723848 0.1428000 0.66511519
#> 2 0.4145463 1.232009 0.4145463 0.09484066
#> 3 0.4137243 1.101267 0.4137243 0.38396964
#> 4 0.3688455 1.985674 0.3688455 0.27438364
#> 5 0.1524447 1.139264 0.1524447 0.81464004
#> 6 0.1388061 1.271326 0.1388061 0.44851634
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

We confirm that all of the imputed values are between 0 and LOD. You can also check the other rows in the data to see that it doesn't affect any observations between 0 and LOD. This is a simple way to achieve the bounds. It only replaces any values greater than LOD with the LOD and any values less than 0 with 0. It doesn't naturally spread them between 0 and LOD. But it does allow you to use different a LOD for each row and column of the data.