# Post-Process Constrain in MICE

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-mice

I am imputing NHANES data where specific cells cannot be above their "detection limits", which are presented in separate columns. Here is a snippet of data to showcase what we are working with:

```
df           

SEQN LBX199 LBX209 LBX199_upper LBX209_upper
21005     NA   0.82    0.1555635    0.0000000
21017   0.45   0.28    0.0000000    0.0000000
21019   0.40   0.30    0.0000000    0.0000000
21020  13.00   3.30    0.0000000    0.0000000
21024     NA     NA    0.1555635    0.3394113
21025     NA   0.30    0.1131371    0.0000000
```

Where columns indicated as, "_upper", are representative of the detection limit. So values imputed cannot exceed these, which can be different for different cells. Values of zero have been replaced for mising values where we do not need imputations.

Going off the vignette for MICE there is some documentation shown for post-process constrain on imputed values.  Here is the link to the vignette:  [vignette](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Passive_Post_processing/Passive_imputation_post_processing.html).

Putting the detection limit column as the upper bounds does not work in the squeeze function as illustrated below:

```
post <- initial_imputed_data$post
post['LBX199'] <- "imp[[j]][, i] <- squeeze(imp[[j]][, i], c(0, imp[['LBX199_upper']][, i]))"
imp <- mice(df, maxit = 1, meth = 'norm.predict', post=post, seed = 3985)
```

This however limits the constrain to a specific bound based on the squeeze function. Here is the function below. Likely the squeeze function needs to be vectorized so that it runs row by row and sets the limit between 0 and what is in the corresponding "_upper" column. Would there be a possibilty of using `apply` or `lapply`in these circumstances?

The first question is how can I run this function row by row so that the correspoding "_upper" column is set to the upper limit?

The second question would be how do I loop this so that each column being imputed in post? I understand that you can specify the columns. Example,

```
post[c('LBX199`, 'LBX209')] <- ...
```

Could you run a for loop through this based on columns that need to be imputed? My attempt at this for loop is below:

```
imputation_cols <- colnames(df[2:36]) #set columns in my data frame

#initial imputation
for(k in imputation_cols){
  initial_imputed_data <- mice(df[,c(2:36)], m = 5, maxit = 1, meth = "norm.predict", seed = 3985)
  meth <-initial_imputed_data$meth
  post <- initial_imputed_data$post
  post['k'] <- "imp[[j]][, i] <- squeeze(imp[[j]][, i], c(0, imp[[select(k+'_upper')]][, i]))"
  imp <- mice(df[,c(2:36)], meth = meth, post=post, seed = 3985)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a different method for imputing missing values. A nearest neighbor method would only select values that already occur in the data. This may help [K-Nearest Neighbor imputation explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327074/k-nearest-neighbor-imputation-explanation).

Comment: MICE is ideal since it will look at the relationship between co-variates during imputation. This is ideal for reconstructing chemical fingerprints when using it in the context of forensic toxicology.

Comment: I answered the post-processing part in another version of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185914/r-mice-imputations-nhanes/74297858#74297858 Do you want to edit this question to highlight the difference between the two questions?